# Accessing EditText ID data returns Null

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm new to Android Kotlin and I can't access the value I inputted on xml for input_mtk ID, which always returns null on Kotlin file.
Here's my code

XML file

```xml
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/matematika"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:text="@string/matematika"
        android:textAppearance="@style/string_form"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/input_bahasa_inggris" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_mtk"
        style="@style/shape2"
        android:layout_marginStart="56dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="230dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:maxLength="5"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/matematika" />
```

Kotlin file

```
class ResultFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_result, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        getData()
    }

    fun getData() {
        var Mat = input_mtk.text.toString()
        Log.e("test", Mat)
    }
}
```

It shows this error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: input_mtk must not be null
        at com.xx.xx.ResultFragment.getData(ResultFragment.kt:38)
        at com.xx.xx.ResultFragment.onViewCreated(ResultFragment.kt:33)
```

if I change
`var Mat = input_mtk.text.toString()`
to
`var Mat = input_mtk?.text.toString()`

shows clearly that input_mtk id returns null
`2021-08-29 16:49:22.158 15887-15887/com.xx.xx E/test: null`

Comment: Are you using dataBinding , View Binding , kotlin syntetics  ?

Comment: @KaruneshPalekar yes I'm using View Binding

Comment: The why haven't you made use of binding in your code ? Do you know how to do that ?

Comment: Are you sure you have right layout? I tried it and it works, this should be valid code. Accepted answer does not necessary has to be done, you can always read from EditText if it is inflated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input_mtk.text` can be null within `onViewCreated()` if the Kotlin synthetic imports or View bindings are not done correctly.
Also, you probably would not have entered anything in the EditText by the time `onViewCreated()` has finished execution

Put it inside a button's click listener:

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/my_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And then in your Kotlin class, access it:

```
var input = ""
my_button.setOnClickListener {
 input = input_mtk.text.toString()
}
```

Here `input` will hold the string from your EditText

Note: I am assuming you are using Kotlin synthetics. If yes, it is recommended to migrate to View Bindings - https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand, what are you trying to do.

`EditText` is a view where the user inputs some data. When you create your app and run it, it has a `null` value aka "there is no content".

You can manually add text in your xml,if you want:

```
  <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_mtk"
        android:text="sometext"
        ... />
```

But its make zero sense since this view is designed to give user opportunity to input own data, and should be empty in most of the cases. Use `TextView` instead

If you want to read inputed data, you can use button:

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener { input_mtk?.text.toString() }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use viewBinding you can do like this

first use viewBinding

```
private lateinit var binding: FragmentResultBinding
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentResultBinding.inflate(inflater)
        return binding.root
    }
```

and change function getData like this

```
private fun getData(){
        val input = binding.inputMtk.text.toString()
        Log.e("FragmentResult", "getData: input: $input" )
    }
```